# Word Mastermind

Tags: word, word-property, mastermind

I have thought of a 6 letter word:

> _ _ _ _ _ _

but I'm not going to tell you what it is. Instead you give me 6 letter words, and I mark them according to the normal rules of Mastermind.

A 'word' can be garbage if you want, e.g. PZQABC, or a normal word like BUTTER. These get marked as 0r1w and 0r2w respectively. The answer word is a real word in this case.

I don't know how hard this is, so here's a few more. If no-one can get it, I'll add more until someone does.

- PESTLE 2r0w
- VIOLIN 0r0w
- PUZZLE 1r1w
- CAMERA 0r2w
- HELIUM 1r1w
- OXYGEN 0r1w
- BANANA 0r0w

Good luck!

Comment: Is the meaning of 0r0w intended to be known to user already

Comment: logical-deduction tag?

Comment: in my humble opinion, this is not enough to deduct the word. i strongly suggest you add at least two to three more guesses to further limit the scope. thanks!

Comment: Should there be a no-computers tag on this? (Seems like it would be very straightforward, but rather boring, to solve by computer.)

Comment: good point @GarethMcCaughan

Comment: (Totally not convinced that those extra words were necessary, by the way.)

Comment: Well, actually, maybe they were. I have a word that solves the original puzzle but doesn't fit one of the new clues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
•   PESTLE 2r0w
•   VIOLIN 0r0w
•   PUZZLE 1r1w
•   CAMERA 0r2w
•   HELIUM 1r1w
•   OXYGEN 0r1w
•   BANANA 0r0w
```

> No: A, I, O, Y, B, N, V, L, H, M, G, X, P, Z, T, R, S 
>  Yes: CUEE 
>  Possible: D, F, J, K, Q, U, C, E, W

How about:

> DEDUCE?

Comment: well done!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks!! This was a fun puzzle! @JonMarkPerry